# Kronecker's theorem in higher dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-curves, real-algebraic-geometry

Recall the following classical theorem of Kronecker: if $P(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a monic irreducible polynomial with all roots on the unit circle $S^1$, then $P(x)$ is a cyclotomic polynomial (and all the roots of $P$ are roots of unity).

I am interested in higher-dimensional versions of Kronecker's theorem. I know at least one such generalization, due to David Boyd and Chris Smyth: if $P \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ has (logarithmic) Mahler measure $0$ then $P$ must be a product of a monomial by polynomials of the form $\Phi_k(x_1^{a_1} \cdots x_m^{a_m})$, where the $\Phi_k$ are cyclotomic polynomials.

Here is an example of what I have in mind. Let $P(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$. The set of toric points of $P$ is the intersection of the curve $C_P : P(x,y)=0$ with the torus $T^2 = (S^1)^2$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Any toric point $(x,y)$ must satisfy $P(x,y)=P(\bar{x},\bar{y})=0$, hence $P(\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y})=0$. So the toric points are contained in $C_P \cap C_P^*$, where $C_P^*$ is the curve defined by $P^*(x,y)=x^d y^d P(\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y})$. If $P$ is not reciprocal, then Bézout's theorem ensures that the set of toric points has cardinality at most $2d^2$.

> Is there a characterization of the non-reciprocal polynomials $P \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ which have $2d^2$ toric points?

I guess that if $P$ has $2d^2$ toric points then all their coordinates must be roots of unity, by using Kronecker's theorem with the resultant of $P$ and $P^*$. I know one example of such a polynomial, namely $P(x,y) = \sum_{i+j \leq d} x^i y^j$.

There is an article of Mikhalkin, *Real algebraic curves, the moment map and amoebas* (Annals of Math 2000) but it is more concerned with the opposite situation where $P$ has 0 or 2 toric points.

Of course, I am also interested in possible generalizations of Kronecker's theorem in other directions.